# Trying to extract data from multiple log files

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging

I am trying to extract data from multiple log files stored in the same directory. I am passing a starting and an ending date as the parameters. The log files are named in ascending order and the format is :

```
2020-07-13T17:30:19, "PUT /wp-admin HTTP/1.0" 200 4975 "https://www.mccann.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/536.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.834.0 Safari/536.1"
2020-07-13T17:31:31, "GET /wp-content HTTP/1.0" 200 5001 "https://landry.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 2.0.1) AppleWebKit/532.0 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/53.0.828.0 Safari/532.0"
```

I have been successful in extracting the data if the start and end date are present in the same file. However, how do i extract the data if the start and end date are in different files.

This is what i have tried so far :

```
reader = csv.reader(open("fakelogfile.log"))
filtered = filter(lambda p: p[0].partition(',')[0] >= '2020-07-26T22:56:36' and 
                  p[0].partition(',')[0] <= '2020-07- 26T23:20:12', reader)
for l in filtered:
  print(','.join(l))
```

Comment: Can you read all lines from all filens to one big list and then do final filtering?

Comment: But wouldnt take a lot of time assuming the log files are very big

Comment: How big are they?

Comment: Each log file around 16 GB

Comment: One solution would be to extract each time interval to separate file, sort each of those files by the time and then use [heapq.merge](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/heapq.html#heapq.merge) to merge them to one file. (as you see, in the documentation is already mention about log files).

Comment: I tried but its really difficult to understand that concept